# For-loop and enumerate with commandline arguments

Tags: python, list, command-line-arguments

I'm playing the game Twilioquest in the Pythonic Temple, and it wants me to create a script that can take any number of commandline arguments and print them into a numbered list.

This is what I have currently:

```
import sys

names = str(sys.argv.pop())

#names2 = ['apples', 'coffee', 'pizza rolls', 'olives']

print('these are your future leaders:')
for index, item in enumerate(names, start=1):
    string_to_print = f'{index}. {item}'
    print(string_to_print)
```

When I execute the code like this, with my own commandline arguments it outputs:

```
these are your future leaders:
1. B
2. a
3. l
4. l
5. s
```

But if I uncomment `names2` and replace all syntax to match I get this

```
these are your future leaders:
1. apples
2. coffee
3. pizza rolls
4. olives
```

which is exactly what I want, how do I make it list commandline arguments properly?

Comment: what is the purpose of `names = str(sys.argv.pop())` ??

Comment: names is supposed to be a variable that takes in commandline arguments, and i was told on the python wiki that .pop is supposed to exclude argument 0 which is just the name of the file

Comment: was it unnecessary?

Comment: In fact `names` will *only* be the program name (sorry, wrong: it will be the last argument you provide)

Comment: thats what i thought but if i put in 0 it does that

Comment: The `pop()` method removes and returns last object from the list.

Comment: let me try again

Comment: oh the last one?

Comment: And don't use `str()` to convert the list of string arguments to a string looking like a list of strings.

Comment: yes so when i include the pop with position it only prints the argument of said position but there still the issue of it listing each letter as a different number, and not each item in the list

Comment: Don't use `pop` until you understand the difference between a function mutating a list and a function returning a new list.